# Integrating a Gaussian Distribution multiplied by 1/x^(2/3), any ideas?

Tags: normal-distribution, integral, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the following function over $x$ and $g$:

$f(z)= \int_{a/z}^{d} \int_{a}^{zg} \frac{e^{-(g-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}}{x^{2/3+1}} dx~dg$

When I integrate over $x$ I get:

$f(z)= 3 \int_{a/z}^{d} {e^{-(g-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}}((gz)^{-2/3}-a^{-2/3})dg$
After re-arrangement we get two terms, one of the is easy to solve, the other one is this:

$f(z)= 3z^{\frac{-2}{3}} \int_{a/z}^{d} {e^{\frac{-(g-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}g^{\frac{-2}{3}}dg$

At this point I am not able to solve the integration.

Any Idea how to do that, I did it in Mathematica and Matlab but I came up empty. Any ideas recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This integrand is trivial to integrate because $x$ does not appear within the arguments to the exponential.  Perhaps you have a typo?

Comment: Okay I see what u mean. The problem is that when I integrate x it becomes in terms of G I will modify the post and show you what is happening. Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: I see--I wasn't paying enough attention to that upper limit.  Why don't you perform the inner integration, then, and ask about the difficult part? :-)

Comment: I just did, I re-modified the post so that the question is more obvious, sorry for not doing that earlier. Once again thx for pointing that out.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the helpful edits.  You might need to find some work arounds, such as approximations, asymptotics, or whatever.  Sometimes these integrals can be obtained in closed form for special values of the limits or of the parameters.  (For instance, $\mu=0$.)  Is there anything you could share with us that would help in that regard?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately the answer has to be in terms of $z$ since $f(z)$ itself will be multiplied by another variable and integrated again. Add to that the equation describes some physical phenomena which has a mean thus I can't set the mean to zero.

Comment: I proposed an edit to the question that correctly evaluates the integral with respect to $x$. $\int_{a}^{gz}x^\frac{-2}{3}=3(gz)^\frac{1}{3}-3a^\frac{1}{3}$.This could possibly make the question easier.

Comment: Anderson, you should double check caburke's proposed edit (as in his comment); if you think it's wrong when it gets approved it can be rolled back... but I think you should look at it closely.

Comment: Thank you very much for that comment. I double checked the equation and corrected it accordingly. The thing is I have this form of: $x^{2/\alpha +1}$ with $2<\alpha<7$ so I choose $\alpha=3$ for the purpose of illustration. Thank you once again.

Comment: The indefinite integral of 
$$
  h(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}x^{-2/3} 
$$
can be expressed by the exponential integral
$$
E_n(x) = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{t^n} dt
$$
as
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[3]{x} \cdot E_{5/6}\big(\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}\big)
$$
But the shift in $x$ makes life much harder of course...

Comment: Thank you very much for that illustration. I get your point, but as you said the existence of the shift makes it harder.

Comment: From what I read, the parameter $a$ is positive. I guess that $d$ is positive too? And what is the range of the $z$ variable? Does it take negative values?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cannot be answered without corrections, and OP hasn't been seen for two years